# Average for similar looking data in a column using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm working on a large data with more than 60K rows.

I have continuous measurement of current in a column. A **code** is measured for a second where the equipment measures it for 14/15/16/17 times, depending on the equipment speed and then the measurement moves to the next **code** and again measures for 14/15/16/17 times and so forth.
Every time measurement moves from one **code** to another, there is a jump of more than **0.15** on the current measurement

The data with top 48 rows is as follows,

| Index | Curr(mA) |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 1.362476 |
| 1 | 1.341721 |
| 2 | 1.362477 |
| 3 | 1.362477 |
| 4 | 1.355560 |
| 5 | 1.348642 |
| 6 | 1.327886 |
| 7 | 1.341721 |
| 8 | 1.334804 |
| 9 | 1.334804 |
| 10 | 1.348641 |
| 11 | 1.362474 |
| 12 | 1.348644 |
| 13 | 1.355558 |
| 14 | 1.334805 |
| 15 | 1.362477 |
| 16 | 1.556172 |
| 17 | 1.542336 |
| 18 | 1.549252 |
| 19 | 1.528503 |
| 20 | 1.549254 |
| 21 | 1.528501 |
| 22 | 1.556173 |
| 23 | 1.556172 |
| 24 | 1.542334 |
| 25 | 1.556172 |
| 26 | 1.542336 |
| 27 | 1.542334 |
| 28 | 1.556170 |
| 29 | 1.535415 |
| 30 | 1.542334 |
| 31 | 1.729109 |
| 32 | 1.749863 |
| 33 | 1.749861 |
| 34 | 1.749861 |
| 35 | 1.736024 |
| 36 | 1.770619 |
| 37 | 1.742946 |
| 38 | 1.763699 |
| 39 | 1.749861 |
| 40 | 1.749861 |
| 41 | 1.763703 |
| 42 | 1.756781 |
| 43 | 1.742946 |
| 44 | 1.736026 |
| 45 | 1.756781 |
| 46 | 1.964308 |
| 47 | 1.957395 |

I want to write a script where similar data of 14/15/16/17 times is averaged in a separate column for each code measurement .. I have been thinking of doing this with pandas..

I want the data to look like

| Index | Curr(mA) |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 1.34907 |
| 1 | 1.54556 |
| 2 | 1.74986 |

Need some help to get this done. Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First get the indexes of every row where there's a jump. Use Pandas' [`DataFrame.diff()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html) to get the difference between the value in each row and the previous row, then check to see if it's greater than `0.15` with `>`. Use that to filter the dataframe index, and save the resulting indices (in the case of your sample data, three) in a variable.

```
indices = df.index[df['Curr(mA)'].diff() > 0.15]
```

The next steps depend on if there are more columns in the source dataframe that you want in the output, or if it's really just `curr(mA)` and index. In the latter case, you can use [`np.split()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.split.html) to cut the dataframe into a list of dataframes based on the indexes you just pulled. Then you can go ahead and average them in a list comphrension.

```
[df['Curr(mA)'].mean() for df in np.split(df, indices)]

> [1.3490729374999997, 1.5455638666666667, 1.7498627333333332, 1.9608515]
```

To get it to match your desired output above (same thing but as one-column dataframe rather than list) convert the list to [`pd.Series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.html) and [`reset_index()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html).

```
pd.Series(
    [df['Curr(mA)'].mean() for df in np.split(df, indices)]
).reset_index(drop=True)

index   0
0   0   1.349073
1   1   1.545564
2   2   1.749863
3   3   1.960851
```

Comment: Small nit: add `drop` to `reset_index(drop=True)` to get rid of the dupe index col

Comment: Also I think your method still works fine even if `df` has more columns. Can just use `np.split(df['Curr(mA)'], indices)` instead, I think.

Comment: True. I think I meant if they want more columns in the output. I'll edit that in.

Comment: Thanks guys, this is very useful! Much appreciated..

Comment: If i want to add another feature in this, where instead of taking mean of all 14/15/16/17 measurements for each code, i take mean of the measurement between  4th to 12th measurement only for each code.. how do i do that?

Comment: I don't totally understand, and I don't think I could answer in the space of a comment anyway. I would recommend posting that as a new question with another [example] and linking to it here.